# C#/ASP.NET - Play dynamically generated WAV file on client click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to play a WAV file that I generate dynamically in a HTTP handler and setting the NavigateUrl property of HyperLink control:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/ServeAudio.ashx" Text="Play Sound" ImageUrl="~/images/speaker_louder_32.png"
                        ToolTip="Play Sound"></asp:HyperLink>
```

But when I click on that link, it opens Windows Media Player - I don't want that.  I just want the sound to play.

I have also tried using a few of the jQuery plugins and they seem to work if I have have a fixed URL to a WAV file but they don't work if I set the URL to my HTTP handler.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTTP analyser like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or browser development tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or dev tools on IE) to see what HTTP headers are sent when you are accessing the WAV file directly.

Then mimic the HTTP headers from your handler by setting the them using [HttpResponse.AppendHeader Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader.aspx). Possibly something like this:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "audio/x-wav");
```

Another trick that might help is to craft the url, so it looks like a file (you should not need this if you can use the appropriate HTTP headers):

```
"~/ServeAudio.ashx/my.wav"
```

Comment: Thanks Maxwell! Your second suggestion did the trick!

I was already adding the content headers but it was still not working.  But just faking a .WAV file in the URL seems to work.

For anyone who is interested - I used this jQuery plugin to play the WAV file: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound_plugin