# Text to speech still plays even after tab or browser close

Tags: asp.net, text-to-speech

I'm developing a text to speech application but the voice still plays even
 when i close the browser.
Here is the code:

```
SpVoice objspeach = new SpVoice();
objspeach.Speak(lbl1.Text.Trim(), SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
objspeach.WaitUntilDone(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

How can I stop voice after browser close?

Is there any code behind method that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the API you're using but I think you can use the Pause method. Look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As this is server side code you'll need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333152/how-to-detect-browser-close-at-server-side-in-asp-net) to detect when the browser closes.

Comment: Thanks are  other asp.net text to speech apis that are available in .net 4.0

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are but it is strange to be using SPVoice in a Web Application as the sound will probably only play on the server (if at all). You're better off using something like this https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/speak-js-text-to-speech-on-the-web/. I can't comment that much on it as I don't know that much about this subject. Typically though, users that require this kind of thing have screen readers installed on their machines already.

Comment: Thanks @Damon.well i am making a course training application which is required to play label text to speech on button click.so iam finding what options do i have.

Comment: can i convert the speech to audio or wav file then play it on the client side . Thanks

Comment: I think so, check this other question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564657/c-asp-net-play-dynamically-generated-wav-file-on-client-click

Comment: Thanks for taking to time reply how can i convert the text to wav file or any webpage playable format ?

Comment: Haven't really used any, try googling for text to speech (TTS) programs, I found this one pretty quickly http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm